# Column selected shows 2 rows when imported to text file sql

Tags: sql-server, replace, delimiter, col

I'm trying to import the below to S3 via text file:

[image]

```
SELECT
    CLI.CLI_ID,
    CLI.CLI_SHORTNAME 'Client_Shortname', 
    REPLACE(CLI.CLI_FIRMNAME, '|','' )'Client_Firmname',
    CLI.CLI_CLIENT_TYPE_ID
    CLI.CLI_CLIENT_TYPE
    CLI.CLI_CLIENT_LOCATION
FROM 
    CLIENT CLI
```

I'm having an issue where the `Client_Firmname` column is breaking into two rows on line 4. 
I'm not sure how to go about this to have it only on that one column.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Client_Firmname field has a carriage return in it.

Maybe add some additional `REPLACE` functions to remove them by replacing it with an empty string.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CLI.CLI_FIRMNAME, '|','' ), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(13), ' ') 'Client_Firmname',
```